# How to log the calling class infos?

Tags: php, codeigniter, logging

I would like to override the CI_Log class to improve the log lines.
I want to log the name of the calling class, and the method.
Example :

```
DEBUG - 2011-04-23 09:21:29 - MY_Class - method --> Router Class Initialized
```

I tried to override the write_log mehod like this :

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class MY_Log extends CI_Log {

    public function write_log($level = 'error', $msg, $php_error = FALSE)
    {
        [...]

        $message .= 
            $level .
            (($level == 'INFO') ? '  - ' : ' - ') .
            $this->router->fetch_class() .
            ' - ' .
            $this->router->fetch_method() .
            ' - ' .
            date($this->_date_fmt). ' --> ' .
            $msg .
            "\n";

        [...]
    }

}
```

But it doesn't work, the `$this->router` is not accessible.
Could you help me?

Comment: Of course, `$this->router` would work only for controllers, so this is not a good idea. I would like this to work for models and so on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think I got it. Here is my code :

```
    [...]

    $message .= $level.(($level == 'INFO') ? '  - ' : ' - ') . date($this->_date_fmt);

    $stack = debug_backtrace();
    // We are searching for the 2nd element of the $stack array beacause :
    // - $stack[0] is always taken by JG_Log->write_log()
    // - $stack[1] is always taken by log_message()
    if (isset($stack[2]['class'])) {
        $message .= ' - ' . $stack[2]['class'] . ' - ' . $stack[2]['function'];
    }

    $message .= ' --> '.$msg."\n";

    [...]
```

I hope that can help others ! :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use somewhere in your method:

```
//$RTR is available from system/core/CodeIgniter.php
global $RTR;
$router_class = $RTR->fetch_class();
$rotuer_method = $RTR->fetch_method();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Because the Log class is intialized before the Router class, I had to use this syntax :
`$router_class = '';
  $router_method = '';
  //$RTR is available from system/core/CodeIgniter.php
  global $RTR;
  if ( isset($RTR)) {
   $router_class = $RTR->fetch_class();
   $router_method = $RTR->fetch_method();
  }`
But this works only for the current controller...

Comment: I explain : I would like that when the controller/model/anything who calls `log_message('debug', 'blabla');` it generates the following line `DEBUG - 2011-04-23 09:21:29 - Class - method --> Router Class Initialized`